# get file where class has been declared/required from

Tags: php

how is it possible to get the file and line where a class has been declared from and/or required?

Answer (score 19):

Use [Reflections](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php) to figure out where a class was declared:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Foobar');
echo $reflector->getFileName();
echo $reflector->getStartLine();
```

Use [`inclued`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inclued-get-data.php) to figure out what was included where.